# Task.ContinueWith runs before the task finishes executing

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In `Main` method of a console application:

```
Do().ContinueWith(t => Do())
    .ContinueWith(t => Do())
    .ContinueWith(t => Do());
```

`Do` is a method that returns `Task`:

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside " + _Counter);
    token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(_Counter++ + " is done");
}, token);
```

And `_Counter` is an integer field:

```
private static int _Counter = 1;
```

When I run, the result is this:

> Inside 1
>   1 is done
>   Inside 2
>   Inside 2
>   Inside 2
>   2 is done
>   3 is done
>   4 is done

So let's assume I have a `Task` called **t** and an `Action<Task>` called **a**.
If I call `t.ContinueWith(a)`, **a** should be called *after* **t** completes, right? And when **a** runs, that should mean whatever delegate **t** calls has ended.

What causes this result? Am I not getting something obvious here?
What I use:

- Windows 8 RTM
- .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: How/Where is _Counter incremented?

Comment: @Henk: Was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I call t.ContinueWith(a), a should be called after t completes, right?

Sure. But since your `Do` function creates a new task, it completes immediately, thus starting the next `Do`. Remove the task creation from `Do` (leaving only the Console.WriteLine stuff) and it should work as expected.

```
    static void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside " + _Counter);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(_Counter + " is done");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Do)
            .ContinueWith(t => Do())
            .ContinueWith(t => Do())
            .ContinueWith(t => Do());
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Here, `Do().ContinueWith(t => Do());` I call `Do()` once. The second one should be called _after_ the first one completes execution (which means a second later).

Comment: "...since your Do function creates a new task, it completes immediately..." yes, but I call `.ContinueWith` method of the returned task and it doesn't complete immidiately.

Comment: The point is that `ContinueWith` doesn't expect a `Task` but an action that will be wrapped inside a task. So if you pass `Do` as a parameter for the `ContinueWith` method, it'll create a task calling `Do`. That is, a task creating a task and exiting immediately.

Comment: Duh, I guess I got it. Then it's ok if I call `Do().ContinueWith(t => Do().Wait)` right?

Comment: @ŞafakGür Basically, what you're trying to do is: `Do().ContinueWith(t => Do().ContinueWith(t2 => Do().ContinueWith(t3 =>Do().ContinueWith(t4 => Do()))));` (yeah that's ugly, and it's obviously not the right way to do it)